# jsonObject in store autoLoad

Tags: wcf, extjs

I have a grid with a pagingtoolbar and a WCF Backend. The store behind the grid is configured like this

```
Ext.define('WonderCarDevi.store.Quotations', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'WonderCarDevi.model.Quotation',
id: 'Quotations',
proxy: {
    timeout : 60000,
    type : 'ajax',
    url: '/blaservice/GetOffers',
    actionMethods:{create: 'GET', read: 'POST', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST'},
    pageSize:50,
    reader: {
        root: 'GetOffersResult',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    },

    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
},
autoLoad: {params:{start: 0, limit: 25}}
//    autoLoad: {jsonData:{start: 0, limit: 25}}
```

The request payload with this request is:

```
start=0&limit=25
```

This doesnt work and the services doesn't send me the right data, however when i do:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url:'/WonderCarService/WonderCarService.svc/GetOffers',
        method:'POST',
        jsonData:{start:0,limit:25},
        success:function (resp, opts) {
            var responseObj = Ext.decode(resp.responseText);
            console.log(responseObj);
        },
        failure:function (resp, opts) {
        },
        scope:this
    });
```

The request payload is:

```
{"start":0,"limit":25}
```

And it does work...

**How do i make my autoload send a json object to the service**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got solved on the Sencha forums by Skirtle.

In his blog he explains how to form the parameters into jsonData using a custom proxy... and it works perfectly

http://skirtlesden.com/articles/custom-proxies

Search for jsonData if ur too lazy ;)